# Dubbuging C++ with VS. Track down varrible change

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a huge program (VS project) which contains global variable. It modifies from hundreds places. Actually it standard STL container (std::vector) and question is how can I track down this particular variable modifications?
In my work I use VS debugger (Prof 2017 15.9.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions which come to my mind:

1. Create another class which will encapsulte this vector.
   Then allow users to use this vector by adding getter returning 
   reference to it.
   Then you can put a breakpoint in getter.
2. Put a memory breakpoint on one of `vector`'s members but it is plantform specific solution which may not work in all scenarios.
3. Replace `std::vector` with your custom type with interface identical to `std::vector`'s which would use original `std::vector` in its internals.
   With this solution you can monitor accesses more precisely.

P.S. remove this global ASAP.

Comment: Thanks, Michał. I have already thought about wrapper, it possible. I also tried to use memory breakpoint but for some reasons VS Debug->New Breakpoint-> Data Breakpoint is disabled in my project